# Expected "," or "..." before numeric constant

Tags: arduino

I´ve tried looking up an answer but I was unable to deduct from any of those what exactly the issue here is. When I try to verify it says "Expected "," or "..." before numeric constant" and highlights "#define Odvesna"

```cpp
#define A1              35
#define B1              15
#define Odvesna         10
#define Prepona         30       


int O(int A1, int B1) {
    int result;
    result = 2*(A1+B1);
    return result;
}
int S(int A1,int B1) {
    int result;
    result = A1*B1;
    return result;
}
int St(int Odvesna,int Prepona) {
    int result;
    result = Prepona*Odvesna/2;
    return result;
}
int Ot(int Odvesna,int Prepona) {
    int result;
    result = sqrt(pow(Odvesna)+pow(Prepona))+ Odvesna+Prepona;
    return result;
}    
void Vystup(O,S,St) {
    Serial.print("O = ");Serial.println(O);
    Serial.print("S = ");Serial.println(S);
    Serial.print("St = ");Serial.println(St);
    Serial.print("Ot = ");Serial.println(Ot);     


/*******************SETUP**********************************/
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Vystup(O,S,St);  

}
/**************MAIN PROGRAM********************************/
void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is a `}` missing at the end of the `Vystup()` function.
2. You can't reuse `#define` names as `variable` names.
3. In this call: `Vystup(O,S,St);` you are passing function pointers as parameters.

Comment: Danny_ds: +1 for not missing the missing bracket I missed.

Answer (score 1):

`int St(int Odvesna,int Prepona) {}` is turned into `int St(int 10,int 30) {}` by the preprocessor, and the compiler doesn't understand what you mean by that.

You have to use other variable names when you define your functions.

Also, `void Vystup(O,S,St) {}` won't work; you are passing functions as parameters, not `int`s as you maybe think.